# Using preg_replace with ASCII characters

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

In my functions.php I added a function that replaces English with German quotation marks. I do this by simple str_replace calls, like this:

```
 $content = str_replace (' &#8220;', ' &#8222;', $content);
```

Now I want to do this with preg_replace instead so I can handle special cases differently. However, this:

```
 $haekchenunten = "&#8220;";
 $regex = /^ . $haekchenunten . /;
 $content = preg_replace ($regex, '&#8222;', $content);
```

Leads to a blank page (PHP Fatal, I'd presume).

How can I use `&#8220;` with preg_replace?

Comment: Have you considered enabling `error_reporting` for once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: My provider does not let me access error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your code, try to use quotation ;-)

```
 $regex = "/^" . $haekchenunten . "/";
```